# How to get data from Ajax POST in my django views function?

Tags: django

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.addFolder input').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        name = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/folder/",
          data: name,
            success: function(result) {
              $('.folders ul li:first-child').after('<li class="bg-color-2 ui-droppable" data-folderid="2">'+name+' <span>0</span></li>');
              $('.addFolder input').val('');
            }
        });
    }
  });
```

How to get data from this Ajax post in my django views function?

**templates:**

```
  <div class="addFolder">
    <span>+</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Folder's name">

  </div>
```

**views:**

```
def folder(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        name = request.POST['name']
        f = Folder.objects.create(name=name, user=user)
        status = "Good"
        return HttpResponse(status)
    else:
        status= "Bad" 
        return HttpResponse(status)
```

Why still I have:

> [30/Nov/2013 14:47:52] "POST /folder/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2294

in logs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always access it in your `request.POST` variable. 
Docs: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST)

Another thing you should fix in js code is `data` parameter.
jQuery docs state the following: `Object must be Key/Value pairs` ([link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

**on updated question**
You receive 403 because you're not sending `csrf` token.
If you have `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` enabled in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, then you'd need to put `{% csrf_token %}` into your form's template, and then send it via js along with your data. 
Like this: `data: {'name': name, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()}`

Comment: Is there an easy way to fix this? How can I send `csrf` token in my case? This is not standard form

Comment: @netman97 You can pass csrf token using djagno template variable {{csrf_token}}
data: {
       name: name,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
},