# I have a dictionary sent by ajax and i want to get it into django view without getting them by key

Tags: python, django

I have sent a dictionary using ajax request in javascript and I want to get it without specifying `request.post['key1']`

I have done this in my view:

```
        def editPermission(request):
          array={}
          array = request.GET('data')
```

But I'm getting this error : Query dict is not callable

Comment: Have you passed it with the GETmethod? I am not sure you can pass a dictionary by GET. Check request.POST

Comment: Key access uses `[...]` brackets, not parentheses: `request.GET['data']`

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20301631/7470786

Comment: It is `request.GET['data']` or `request.GET.get('data')`.

Comment: i am using post method in ajax and i have done x = request.POST['data'] where data is the dictionary and an error occured: MultiValueDictKeyError

Comment: If the  ajax call uses POST then you won't get anything in `request.GET` obviously, and if `request.POST['data']` raises a KeyError then obviously  no key named '"data" has been posted. Now since we don't have any idea of what is actually posted there's no way to help - but __you__ should know what you posted, don't you ?

Comment: As a side note, trying anything that comes to mind expecting it will magically work (instead of properly researching why something doesn't work as expected) is a well known antipattern known as "programming by accident" or "programming by permutation", and it won't take you very far.  Learning to debug AND reading the doc are two required skills if you expect to do anything as a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.GET` is a [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict), it cannot be called.

you can try out:

```
items = request.GET.items()
```

Comment: how to loop through them in django to change a querydict to dict?

Comment: just like normal dictionary:
for key, val in items():
    print key, val